# Tkinter treeview scroll bar not shown properly

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have created a window application using tkinter with multiple frames.  In code snippet below, frame frm1 I have added a treeview widget which works fine, but as soon as I associate a vertical and horizontal scrollbar - the tree view widget is show shrinked to the top left corner.  Why is this happening?

See below the code snippet

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import BOTTOM, TOP, RIGHT, LEFT, SUNKEN, W, X, Y, NO, VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL, DISABLED, NONE, S, N, E, W

class myApp:
    def __init__(self, wnd):
        self.wnd = wnd
        self.wnd.title(f"My App")
        self.wnd.geometry('1300x700')
        self.wnd.resizable(False, False)

        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.wnd, width=1300, height=90, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black",bg='yellow')
        self.center = tk.Frame(master=self.wnd, width=1300, height=600, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black",)
        self.status_frame = tk.Frame(master=self.wnd, width=1300, height=22, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1,bg='red')

        self.wnd.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.wnd.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.wnd.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
   
        self.top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky="n")
        self.center.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="n")
        self.status_frame.grid(row=2, sticky="nsew")

##############################

        self.center.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.center.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
   
        self.ctr_left = tk.Frame(self.center, width=900, height=600, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
        self.ctr_right = tk.Frame(self.center, width=400, height=600, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
   
        self.ctr_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.ctr_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
   
###############################       
    
        self.ctr_left.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.ctr_left.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
   
        self.frm1 = tk.Frame(self.ctr_left, width=900, height=550, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", bg='green')
        self.frm2 = tk.Frame(self.ctr_left, width=900, height=50, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1,bg='purple')
   
        self.frm1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
        self.frm2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="sw")

################################
   
        self.ctr_right.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.ctr_right.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
   
        self.frm3 = tk.Frame(self.ctr_right, width=400, height=550, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", bg='orange')
        self.frm4 = tk.Frame(self.ctr_right, width=400, height=50, highlightcolor="black", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1,bg='pink')
   
        self.frm3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
        self.frm4.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="se")
   
    
        #add treeview to frame frm1
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("clam")
        self.style.configure("Treeview",
            background="silver",
            foreground="black",
            fieldbackground="silver")
        self.style.map("Treeview", background=[('selected','green')])
   

        self.my_tree = ttk.Treeview(master=self.frm1, height=26)
   
        # define our columns
        self.my_tree['columns'] = ("Date & Time", "Type", "Log Message")
        self.my_tree.column("#0", width=0, minwidth=0, stretch=NO)
        self.my_tree.column("Date & Time", anchor=W, width=140, minwidth=140)
        self.my_tree.column("Type", anchor=W, width=70, minwidth=70)
        self.my_tree.column("Log Message", anchor=W, width=685, minwidth=400, stretch=True)

        # create headings
        self.my_tree.heading("#0", text="", anchor=W)
        self.my_tree.heading("Date & Time", text="Date & Time", anchor=W)
        self.my_tree.heading("Type", text="Type", anchor=W)
        self.my_tree.heading("Log Message", text="Log Message", anchor=W)
        self.my_tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
   
        #add scrollbar to treevew widget my_tree
        self.ytree_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.my_tree, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.my_tree.yview)
        self.xtree_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.my_tree, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.my_tree.xview)       
        self.ytree_scroll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nse")
        self.xtree_scroll.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ews")
   
        self.my_tree.configure(yscroll=self.ytree_scroll.set, xscroll=self.xtree_scroll.set)      
    

        #add scrollbar to frame widget frm3
#        self.ytree_scroll1 = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frm3, orient=VERTICAL)
#        self.xtree_scroll1 = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frm3, orient=HORIZONTAL)       
#        self.ytree_scroll1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nse")
#        self.xtree_scroll1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ews")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    application = myApp(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the scrollbars not on the treeview itself, but on the same parent window. So you should do it like this:

```
    self.ytree_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frm1, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.my_tree.yview)
    self.xtree_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(master=self.frm1, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=self.my_tree.xview)       
    self.ytree_scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nse")
    self.xtree_scroll.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ews")
```

After that you should change some things because this gives some whitespace on the neighbouring frames.